# Is it necessary to concatenate scripts if I load scripts with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, workflow, concatenation, systemjs

I always read on the web **"Use concatenation & minification for a faster site"**.

But I'm wondering, Is it necessary to concatenate my scripts if I am using AMD library like *requireJs* or *SystemJs* to load the scripts asynchronously?

Comment: it's never necessary, and how can you fetch the middle of a big concat'd file from require (without server processing)? putting all your scripts into one file these days results in a page that is actually slower than pipeline-ing 2-4 connections would be. you could also use something like browserify to populate the require() instead of grabbing URLs...

Comment: Always minimize.  There's a tradeoff between lots of small files and one giant concatenated file.  That tradeoff involves download speed, number of simultaneous things that can be downloaded, mazimizing browser caching, reducing dead code for any given page, etc...  There is no blanket statement that always achieves optimal results.  You probably want to have a small number of highly cacheable files.  Not 20, but doesn't have to be all in one giant file either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it is especially important for applications with AMD libraries. One of the key reasons for optimization is to reduce the number of HTTP requests made to the server. Also, the front-end will be faster without network latency in the picture. Using AMD makes writing client side code seem more organized and promotes SOC, both can result in having a ton of files needed for a single feature.